# regular expression : with a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, quoting

```
arrFormat=( jpg jpeg bmp tiff png )
varExtension="jpg"

for elem in "${arrFormat[@]}"
do
  echo "${elem}"
  # do something on $elem #
done


#for i in $( find -E . -iregex '.*\.($arrFormat)' )  ; do   #problem
#for i in $( find -E . -iregex '.*\.("$arrFormat")' )  ; do #problem
#for i in $( find -E . -iregex '.*\.($varExtension)' )  ; do        #problem
#for i in $( find -E . -iregex '.*\.("$varExtension")' )  ; do  #problem

for  i in $( find -E . -iregex '.*\.(jpg|png)' )  ; do # this works fine

  echo "${i}"
  # do something on $i #
done
```

So it seems that the regular expression has a problem with variable(s)
How can I give an array or just one variable as argument to a regular expression

Shell info, MACINTOSH :

```
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the single quotes. Variables aren't expanded in single quotes (from `man bash`):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the  literal  value 
>   of each character within the quotes.

If you want to use a variable, you need double quotes. To illustrate:

```
$ foo="bar"
$ echo '$foo'
$foo
$ echo "$foo"
bar
```

So, in your case, you want something like:

```
for i in $( find -E . -iregex ".*\.$varExtension")  ; do
```

Or, better since the above [can't deal with strange file names](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020):

```
find -E . -iregex ".*\.$varExtension" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
```

Or, forget the loop and have `find` do whatever the job is for you:

```
find -E . -iregex ".*\.$varExtension" -exec something {} \;
```